# Powerpoint VBA - Presentation.Slides(index) giving "Object doesn't support property error"

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to create a custom Powerpoint toolbar that generates a toolbar of useful layouts that I am saving in a 'templates.pptx' deck as I come across them.

The templates.pptx has a series of sections in it, and I am adding the slides into the respective sections. I want the VBA to:

1. Be given a specific section (in the example below, section #1)
2. find all the slides in that section
3. Loop over each slide and generate an XML button into a string, which is passed back into the toolbar on load

Process menu calls `getProcessContent` on load:

```
Sub getProcessContent()
    Dim xml As String
    xml = generateXML(1)
    MsgBox (xml)
    getProcessContent = xml

End Sub
```

This calls a generic generate XML function that takes a section ID parameter

```
Function generateXML(sectionId)
    Dim template As presentation
    Dim path As String
    Dim xml As String
    Dim sectionName As String
    Dim Slide As Integer
    Dim slideObj As Slide
    Dim slideTitle As String
    
    'Load template layouts
    'path = AddIns("km_ppt_toolbar").path
    path = "[HIDDEN]\ppt toolbar\v2"
    Set template = Presentations.Open(path & "\templates.pptx")
    
    'Generate blank XML string
    xml = ""
    
    FirstSlide = template.SectionProperties.FirstSlide(sectionId)
    
    Lastslide = (FirstSlide + template.SectionProperties.SlidesCount(sectionId) - 1)
    
    For Slide = FirstSlide To Lastslide
        ' Add a button for each slide
        Set slideObj = template.Slides(Slide)
        slideTitle = slideObj.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    
        slideXML = "<button id=""" & slide & """ label=""" & slideTitle & """ imageMso=""HappyFace"" size=""normal"" onAction=""InsertSlide " & slide & """ />"
        xml = xml & slideXML
    Next Slide
    
    presentation.Close
    
    generateXML = xml
    
End Function
```

When I run the `getProcessContent` sub, I get a Run Time Error on the first slide in the For loop, highlighting the `slideObj = presentation.Slides(Slide)` line saying "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: `presentation.Slides(Slide)` returns a Slide Object, so you are missing a `Set` when assigning it to the `slideObj`-variable. Also, you should use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables with the correct object type to avoid errors.

Comment: I thenk get a Type Mismatch error on the next line?

Comment: At the next line, you need to remove `Set`. `Text` is a String. In VBA, you need to use `Set` to assign objects, but not for regular ("primitive") variables like strings or numbers.

Comment: Okay, actually, you've set me off in right direction, have updated the question as I now get another problem in the first function - `getProcessContent = xml` gives an `Expected Function or Variable Error`

Comment: Ah - `getProcessContent` needs to be a function, not a Sub right?

Comment: `getProcessContent` is a Sub, you can't assign a value to it. If you want to return the generated xml string, you need to convert it to a function (like `generateXML`). Else, remove that statement (but you need to make up your mind what to do with the generaed XML, else it is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @FunThomas helped point me in the right direction on this one, essentially my use of `set` or not was, shall we say, wacky...

Fixing the function in question, then threw up another challenge, which I fixed having read a few more bits on the `DynamicMenu` element.

Final working set of functions are below. These now generate the XML correctly. Unfortunately the buttons are not displaying in my menu currently. This is an issue, I'm sure, with my XML text and not the function's themselves. Once I figure it out, I will post an update.

```
' Have to add in IRibbonControl and returnedVal bits in order to pass XML back to ribbon
Sub getProcessContent(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    Dim xml As String
    xml = generateXML(1)
    returnedVal = xml
End Sub
```

```
Function generateXML(sectionId)
    Dim template As presentation
    Dim path As String
    Dim xml As String
    Dim sectionName As String
    Dim Slide As Integer
    Dim slideObj As Slide
    Dim slideTitle As String
    
    'Load template layouts
    'path = AddIns("km_ppt_toolbar").path
    path = "[HIDDEN]\ppt toolbar\v2"
    Set template = Presentations.Open(path & "\templates.pptx")
    
    'Generate blank XML string [EDIT - added menu schema]
    xml = "<menu xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">"
    
    FirstSlide = template.SectionProperties.FirstSlide(sectionId)
    
    Lastslide = (FirstSlide + template.SectionProperties.SlidesCount(sectionId) - 1)
    
    For Slide = FirstSlide To Lastslide
        ' Add a button for each slide
        Set slideObj = template.Slides(Slide)
        slideTitle = slideObj.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    
        slideXML = "<button id=""" & Slide & _
            """ label=""" & slideTitle & _
            """ onAction=""InsertSlide " & Slide & """ />"
            
        xml = xml & slideXML
    Next Slide
    
    ' Add menu close tag
    xml = xml & "</menu>"
    
    template.Close
    
    generateXML = xml
    
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

The "The object does not support this property or method" error you get indicates that there is a problem in the presentation.Slides(Slide) part of your code. You probably didn't define a variable named presentation when trying to access the slides from the presentation object. Instead, you should access the slides from the template you defined.

```
Function generateXML(sectionId)
Dim template As Presentation
Dim path As String
Dim xml As String
Dim sectionName As String
Dim Slide As Integer
Dim slideObj As Slide
Dim slideTitle As String


'path = AddIns("km_ppt_toolbar").path
path = "[HIDDEN]\ppt toolbar\v2"
Set template = Presentations.Open(path & "\templates.pptx")


xml = ""

FirstSlide = template.SectionProperties.FirstSlide(sectionId)

LastSlide = (FirstSlide + template.SectionProperties.SlidesCount(sectionId) - 1)

For Slide = FirstSlide To LastSlide
    
    Set slideObj = template.Slides(Slide)
    slideTitle = slideObj.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

    slideXML = "<button id=""" & Slide & """ label=""" & slideTitle & """ imageMso=""HappyFace"" size=""normal"" onAction=""InsertSlide " & Slide & """ />"
    xml = xml & slideXML
Next Slide

template.Close

generateXML = xml

End Function
```

I updated the variable name to lastslide